# Apply minus top margins using JS CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am calculating a height of an element using JavaScript then I am applying that height as padding-top to another element as you can see below:

```
 $(window).on("ready resize", function () {
        if (window.innerWidth > 1024) {
            var pageTop = $("#header.header-fixed .content").outerHeight() + "px";
            $("#page .topSection").css("padding-top", pageTop);
        } else {
            var pageTop = $("#secondHeader").outerHeight() + "px";
            $("#page .topSection").css("padding-top", pageTop);
        }
    });
```

My question is, how can I apply that height as margin-top "-" to the same element as well?
so for example if the #header height is 100px; the margin -top for .topSection will be -100px

------------- **Update** ---------------------------------------

Thank you! the answers below helped!

I am experiencing another problem which has been a result of applying the minus margins!
Here is the code I am currently using...

```
//Fixed header optimizer
    $(window).on("ready resize", function() {
        if (window.innerWidth > 1024) {
            var pageTop = $("#header").outerHeight() + "px";        
            $("#page .topSection").css({"padding-top": pageTop, "margin-top": "-"+pageTop});
        } else {
            var pageTop = $("#secondHeader").outerHeight() + "px";
            $("#page .topSection").css({"padding-top": pageTop, "margin-top": 0});
        }
    });
```

How can I make it not apply these margins if the #header had a class of .header-fixed?

Comment: you mean something like this?: 
    $(element).css('margin-top', $(element).css('height'));

Comment: You can just do `$("#page .topSection").css("margin-top", '-'+pageTop);` That will converter positive margin into negative

Comment: doesn't negative margins mean that your design is not proper??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try concatenating the pageTop string with a "-":

```
$(window).on("ready resize", function () {
        if (window.innerWidth > 1024) {
            if(!$('#header').hasClass("header-fixed")) {
                var pageTop = $("#header").outerHeight() + "px";
                $("#page .topSection").css({"padding-top": pageTop, "margin-top": "-" + pageTop});
            }
        } else {
            if(!$('#header').hasClass("header-fixed")) {
                var pageTop = $("#secondHeader").outerHeight() + "px";
                $("#page .topSection").css({"padding-top": pageTop, "margin-top": "-" + pageTop});
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! this helped, please can you take a look at the updated question?

Comment: do and if condition and to check $("#header").hasClass("header-fixed")

Comment: I incorporated the if statements above. (I dont know exactly what you code is trying to do, so the if statement I added to the else may not be necessary)

Comment: Thank you! it is nearly working! I simply want to remove "margin-top": "-" + pageTop from the #header if it has the class header-fixed so the opposite

Comment: the above code uses the "!" to switch the boolean in the if. i.e. if `$('#header').hasClass("header-fixed")` is TRUE then the "!" makes it FALSE... i.e. the above is only running the pageTop code if the `#header` does not have the class `.header-fixed`. if this is not the behavior you want, simply remove the "!"

Comment: Been playing around with it, for some reason it broke the code, it isn't working no more :/

Comment: Thank you very very much!! Been trying to solve this for ages -.-

Answer (score 3):

```
.css({"padding-top": pageTop, "margin-top": "-"+pageTop})
```

Answer (score 2):

try following code,

```
$(window).on("ready resize", function () {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1024) {
        var pageTop = $("#header.header-fixed .content").outerHeight() + "px";
        $("#page .topSection").css({"margin-top": "-" + pageTop, "padding-top" :  pageTop});
    } else {
        var pageTop = $("#secondHeader").outerHeight() + "px";
        $("#page .topSection").css({"margin-top": "-" + pageTop, "padding-top" : pageTop});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
$("#page .topSection").css({"padding-top": pageTop,"margin-top":"-"+pageTop});
```

instead of

```
$("#page .topSection").css("padding-top", pageTop);
```